# How to parse HTML with embeded PHP code?

Tags: php, dom

I'm doing some HTML DOM manipulations:

```
function parse_html($html) {
    $dom->loadHTML($html);
    libxml_clear_errors();

    // Parse DOM 

    return $dom->saveHTML();
}
```

The problem is my HTML contains some PHP code and some of them is transformed in HTML entities. For example if `$html` contains this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd">
<?php // lang=es
    $pwd = $parameter['pwd'];
    $url = $parameter['url'];
?>

<p>
    You are now registered. Go to -&gt;
    <a href="<?php echo $url ?>">control panel</a> 
    to change the settings.
</p>
```

It's transformed in this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head><meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"></head>
<body>
<?php // lang=es
    $pwd = $parameter['pwd'];
    $url = $parameter['url'];
?><p> You are now registered. Go to -&gt; <a href="&lt;?php%20echo%20%24url%20?&gt;">control panel</a> to change the settings.
</p>
</body>
</html>
```

The `<?php echo $url ?>` is converted in entities, but I cannot use a function like *html_entity_decode* because it will decode also some entities that must remain entities.

How can I parse a DOM that contains PHP code?

Comment: Do you have the option of running the HTML through the PHP pre-processor first?  That will give you pure HTML which you can then parse.

Comment: Well, if you go to rainbow land you can paint all things in the colors you like best and re-order them without physical constraints. In programming we're normally tight to so called standards and in a DomDocument PHP is undefined *unless* you have got a *valid* XML document with *valid* processing instructions. Otherwise it happens what you face.

Comment: @user1161318 No, this is a pre-parser for the project itself

Comment: @Ivon: If so, switch to valid X(HT)ML with PHP as [processing instructions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Processing_Instruction).

Comment: Perhaps replace all instances of <?php x ?> with a placeholder which the parser can handle and then pop the code back in afterwards?

Comment: Not standard DOM, but Tidy is able to handle Nodes for PHP, ASP and the like next to the common HTML ones. See http://php.net/manual/en/class.tidynode.php

Comment: @BenSwinburne: That's been the solution I found. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I've found is to create a couple of functions to encode/decode the PHP strings.

```
function encode_php($html) {
    return preg_replace_callback('#<\?php.*\?>#imsU', '_encode_php', $html);
}

function _encode_php($matches) {
    return 'PHP_ENCRYPTED_CODE_BEGIN'.base64_encode($matches[0]).'PHP_ENCRYPTED_CODE_END';
}

function decode_php($html) {
    return preg_replace_callback('#PHP_ENCRYPTED_CODE_BEGIN(.*)PHP_ENCRYPTED_CODE_END#imsU', '_decode_php', $html);
}

function _decode_php($matches) {
    return base64_decode($matches[1]);
}
```

It's important to choose a prefix and a suffix that you are sure don't appear in your files. This solution has been tested with 2500 HTML files and it works.

Answer (score 0):

when where and how are you building the `$html` variable?  it is at that spot and time where and when you will want to parse the php inside.  If you try to spit it out after it will be spit out like just a string and will not be parsed.

To be more clear, build the `$html` variable with the php included at that time.  Or perhaps you are building a template instead.  In that case you will do it differently.

In case you are trying to fill in php content after the `$html` variable has been put in play, you can instead use [str_replace()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php), or some other similar function to some effect.